# Remove mint 12 dvd version and leave windows 7

Tags: windows-7, linux, partitioning, linux-mint

I dual booted my xp, installing linux mint 12 lisa with no problem.
My brother decided to do the same, he dual booted his windows 7, installing linux mint 12 cd version, then upgraded to the dvd version, however there's problems. Mint freezes on login screen when using kde or gnome.

**if that happened to you and you know about a QUICK fix tell me, otherwise keep reading :)**

so he decided to remove it and leave windows, the question is how? We don't have windows 7 cd, it was installed on his pc when he bought the laptop.
we don't want to reinstall windows. we don't want to lose any data and we don't want to back up the data because we don't have an external hard disk and because it take a long time.
we don't care about the files that are now on mint, and we will not reinstall mint.

**In short:** What is the easiest, fastest and smoothest way to remove mint without damaging windows 7? we want to resize the windows so it can use the whole computer, he has gnome and kde on his pc + some software

**duplicate question**? maybe but i don't know if the answers are useful

i found this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/162907/remove-linux-mint-9-partition-leave-windows-7-okay), but i don't know if i can trust the answers

the accepted answer won't work coz you'll have to use windows 7 cd which i do not have

the 2nd answer: would it work??? without a win 7 cd?

the 3d answer, well the answer is not voted up and it's for mint 11 I don't know if i can trust it

**As i said i have linux mint 12 cd version, but we then upgrade it to the dvd version from the internet**

Comment: this problem occurred even before he installed kde... so kde is not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a way to create a valid bootloader. This will either be GRUB or the native Windows bootloader. Once you've secured a way to install a bootloader, you can just delete the Mint partition and resize the NTFS partition and filesystem to reclaim the space.

Don't mess with your main computer if you don't have install media for every single OS you might conceivably want to use.