# How do I merge Linux partition to Windows 10 partition?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, partitioning

I have partitioned my SSD to dual boox Ubuntu and Windows 10. Currently my Ubuntu partition size is just 30 GB (I know, I should allocated more space to this partition initially but now damage is done) and I am running out of space.

My Windows partiton has 150 GB empty but when I tried to further partition Windows 10 partition, Windows Disk Management utility is allowing me to get only 1 GB partition. I googled for this issue but couldn't find anything.

One solution I have is - remove Linux partition and expand Windows partition to consume this Linux partition. I found [this question on SU](https://superuser.com/questions/162907/how-do-i-remove-a-linux-partition-and-expand-the-windows-partition-to-consume-th) which talks about my problem BUT solution given is for Windows 7. Accepted answer suggests that I need Windows installation disk which I don't have.

So does anyone have come across this situation? If so, please suggest some way out in terms of `Windwos 10`.

Comment: In order to shrink the Windows partition.  You will need to get rid of the system files that cannot be moved (i.e. the page file, hibernation file, ect).  Once you do that you will be able to shrink the partition.  However, the unallocated space will likely NOT be created in a location on the partition layout, where the unallocated space can be merged into the Linux partition.  How you solve that problem is different from the inability to shrink the Windows partition, so which problem, are you seeking to solve?  It is trivial to download a Windows 7 or Windows 10 ISO.

Comment: Do you have to use dual boox? Ubuntu in VM can solve most problems. Or Ubuntu in VM for most usage plus Ubuntu on another box.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, download first 'multisystem' or 'unetbootin'.. Then download Hirens and make a boot flash drive. Then boot from it... Under Disk Director you can shrink your windows. Then send the allocated space after the Linux partition and then extend the Linux drive. Restart and you are good to go